# How to output multiple keys with one common value in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, key

I am working on a Java program. I am trying to output multiple keys with one common value.

My code:

```
Map<String, String> patients = new HashMap<>();
        patients.put("555", "Adam");
        patients.put("666", "Adam");
        patients.put("66r", "PAM");
        Set<String> list = new TreeSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> listOfPatients : patients.entrySet()) {
            list.add(listOfPatients.getValue() + " - " + String.join(",",listOfPatients.getKey()));
            System.out.println(list);
        }
```

However, I get the wrong output.

The output I want:

```
Adam - 555,666
```

The output I get:

```
[Adam - 555, Adam - 666, PP - 66r]
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your code?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Java 8 Stream API:**

**Logic Here:**

Here you can use `groupingBy` feature in java stream API and do the groupingBy based on value and then join the elements using `Collectors.joining` while collecting it.

*You can try it by using java 8 stream API as shown below:*

```
Map<String,String> map = patients.entrySet().stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
              Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,Collectors.joining(","))));
```

**Output:**

```
{Adam=555,666, PAM=66r}
```